# Как получить доступ к объектом из другого класса?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, uikit

Создан собственный класс. В методе `viewDidLoad` создан объект этого собственного класса. Как правильно получить доступ к этому объекту из другого метода, например, из `touchBegin`?

Comment: Не силён в objective-c, но полагаю как в любом ООП можно экземпляр объекта присвоить переменной/полю/свойству собственного класса. Эта переменная будет доступна внутри всего класса, в любом методе.

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyClass* myObject;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.myObject = [MyClass new];
}    

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   self.myObject = nil;// или что угодно
}    

@end
```

Comment: Спасибо! Правильно ли я понял, что добавление `@property` к классу, в котором я хочу видеть свой объект - единственный правильный способ? Изначально задача была такая: в `viewDidLoad ` создается несколько объектов моего класса, в котором есть свойство типа `UIView`, и там же я их отображаю. В методе `touchBegan` я хочу понять, до какого из `View` я дотронулся. Неужели для этого мне придется плодить `@property`?

Comment: или проперти или переменные класса, если несколько объектов то можешь кинуть их в массив и сделать сам массив проперти